# Text fadeIn fadeOut issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/8SQA8/1/

When fadeIn and fadeOut in Chrome, text will be a little bit distortion in a flah, IE and Firefox works fine, how to fix it?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">aaaaaaaa</div>
    <div class="inner">bbbbbbbb</div>
    <div class="inner">ssssssss</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
}
.inner {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200x;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var divs = $('.inner'),
    current = 0,
    divSize = divs.size();

divs.filter(':gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() {
    current++;
    divs.filter(':visible').fadeOut();
    divs.eq(current).fadeIn();

    if ((current + 1) === divSize) {
         current = -1;   
    }
},3000);
```

Comment: that will probably also depend on the platform, on my chrome/macpro i see it right. However if you want a smoother effect, use **HTML5 transitions**, they are rendered usually 100% by the GPU

Comment: @rupps Chrome on Windows will sometimes mess up transition animations even if they are animated with CSS3 just like his demo :)

Comment: sorry to hear that.. In my experience they work pretty cool unless there's complicated stuff behind them such as fixed divs, or you mingle with the z-indexes on hover effects ... Also you can check chrome://gpu to see if hardware acceleration is 100% enabled, that really helps. Most of the problems are caused by buggy drivers (that nobody takes the effort to correct)

Comment: They are all Hardware Accelerated on my Windows machine, and [I changed @吳承諺 's demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8SQA8/2/) to use CSS3 transitions. The text is still distorted when animating.

Comment: I'm unable to help then, it's displaying perfect on my computer

Comment: @rupps - Chrome sucks at animations on Windows. I have been seeing this bug for some time already. Chrome can't even handle a simple `scale` transformation I had on a project I made... the object becomes transparent during the animation and reappears when the animation is done but when I test it on another browser it worked perfectly.

Comment: Do these problems show up in other webkit-based browsers for Windows as well, like Opera-10+ or Safari? Mind that Google has recently forked WebView into Blink to optimize and rewrite big parts of the  graphics engine. Maybe these are initial problems. And seem to me they are related to the **-webkit-backface-visiblity** hack ...